# How to access properties of a circle inside groups of a group on d3

Tags: d3.js

I want to draw series of circles. Then, for each circle, I want to define three of them with the following radius: [r, r/2, r/4].
How do I do that?

I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
var grupos = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data([1,2,4])
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return("dots" + d); })
    .selectAll(".dot")
        .data(getData(0))
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.party})
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return co(d); })
        .call(position)
        .sort(order)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be nesting the elements that you appending, then you need to provide an array of arrays to the first `.data` call.  Then, after that you can reference it like I have below for the nested data calls.

Here is an example that may help you get a bit further along.

Mike's [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) page may help you as well.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                             .attr("width", 400)
                             .attr("height", 300),
    colours = d3.scale.category10(),
    r = 20,
    
    data = [
             [ 1, 2, 4],
             [ 2, 4, 8]
           ];

svg.append("g").selectAll("g.circles")
                 .data(data)
               .enter().append("g")
                 .attr("class", "circles")
                 .selectAll("circle.dot")
                   .data(function(d) { return d; })
                 .enter().append("circle")
                   .attr("class", function(d) { return "dot " + d; })
                   .attr("cx", function(d, i, j) { return 50 + i * 50; })
                   .attr("cy", function(d, i, j) { return 50 + j * 50; })
                   .attr("r", function(d) { return r / d; })
                   .attr("fill", function(d, i , j) { return colours(r/d); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify the following to nest groups; it is essentially identical to nesting a `g` group within an `svg` document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Nested circles</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          var radii = [4, 2, 1];
          var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

          var svg = d3.select("body")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("id", "foo")
                      .attr("width", 200)
                      .attr("height", 200);

          var bar = svg.append("g").attr("id", "bar");

          bar.selectAll("circle")
             .data(radii)
             .enter()
             .append("circle")
             .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "circle_" + i; })
             .attr("r", function(d) { return 20*d; })
             .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; })
             .attr("cx", 100)
             .attr("cy", 100);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```